# Installed module could not be found in python environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, module

I have a python environment and need to work with matplotlib module. It is installed in `env` and when I use command `pip list`, it is shown in modules name list. But when I want to import it in my script or calling command `python -m matplotlib` module could not be found in `env`:

"No module named matplotlib.__main__; 'matplotlib' is a package and cannot be directly executed"

Comment: The `Module not Found` can be explained if the python being used to execute the script is not same one from the environment. As for the `python -m matlplotlib` it is simply an error as matlpoltlib itself doesnt have a `__main__` script to be ran

Comment: Would you explain what should I do too use this module in my script? Outside environment it work perfectly.

Comment: If you have installed matplotlib in a virtual environment, then importing it into your script should be enough, the only thing to be made sure is that when running the script, you are using the python from your virtual environment, and that is dependant on what virtual env manager are you using

Comment: Well I have installed it in environment. It's in windows and after calling `activate` command it goes to environment and I installed it here. The problem is when calling module in environment it won't find it and pass this error that I posted in question.

Comment: Actually the module itself can't run, its actually like trying to run a directory, what you want to do is after activating the env you want to run the script where the module is imported. If that still causes an error then it might be an installation or path issue

Answer (score 0):

Although some python packages can be run as standalone program (with `python -m <the_package_name>`) this does not apply to all python packages. In order to be run with the `-m` flag, the package must explicitly support this. `matplotlib` or e.g. also `numpy` do not support this. You can use functions and classes of these packages by importing them into another python script with the `import` statement.

```
import matplotlib
```

or

```
import numpy
```